# How would i check if the value in the table is equal to the _G variable string?

Tags: lua

How would i check the table to see if the value in the table matches the _G.User = "" variable?

```
_G.Name = "Bod"
------------------------------------------------------------
local CorrectUsers = {
  "Username1",
  "Username2",
  "Username3",
  "Username4",
  "Username5",
}
------------------------------------------------------------
for i,v in pairs(CorrectUsers, _G.User) do
 if table.find(CorrectUsers, _G.User) then
  print("Correct User")
 else
  print("Incorrect User")
 end
end
```

https://replit.com/@BloodThirstyy/SimpleMultiStepWhitelist

Comment: One trick I like doing when I must compare against tables is reversing an array into keys, i.e `local allowedUsers = { User1 = 0, User2 = 0, User3 = 0 }` then performing a check with `allowedUsers[desiredUsername]` -- it lets me skip iteration in very large tables and stays fast due to Lua's impressive hash performance. This is something you could do, but going your route, `for k, v in pairs(CorrectUsers) do if v == DesiredUsername then .. end` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Isn't 0 a falsy value in Lua?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for i,v in pairs(CorrectUsers, _G.User) do
>  if table.find(CorrectUsers, _G.User) then
> ```

`pairs` only takes one argument. There is no `table.find` in Lua's table library.

In your snippet `_G.User` is undefined. `_G.Name` is unused.

Also usually there is no need to access globals through `_G`. Just write `User`.

To find something in a table you traverse over the table and compare each element with the value you are looking for.

So for a table like

```
local CorrectUsers = {
  "Bob",
  "John",
  "Susan",
  "Daniel",
  "Zoe",
}
```

You'd simply do

```
for i, v in ipairs(CorrectUsers) do
  if v == "Daniel" then
    print("found Daniel")
  end
end
```

Alternatively you can build a look up table:

```
local isCorrectUser = {
  Bob = true,
  Jane = true,
  John = true,
}
```

And then

```
if isCorrectUser.Jane then
  print("found Jane")
end
```

As building such look up tables can become tedious you can simply create one from your user list.

```
local isCorrectUser = {}
for i, v in ipairs(CorrectUsers) do
  isCorrectUser[v] = true
end
```

Using a lookup table becomes useful if you are checking values very frequently as you will not have to traverse over the table very time.